# Inserting mouseover event to custom label created with SVGRenderer, highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create a custom credits with a tooltip, I've found and example of setting an event listener to title and add tooltip to chart title using `mouseover`. But for some reason adding this event listener doesn't seem to work with my custom label created with SVGRenderer, what am I missing??

My attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/bernardo0marques/ovhx39c8/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that in your example, in the load callback you are trying to add a custom event to the label which doesn't exist because it wasn't rendered yet.

Check console: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u07y5gnr/

To fix it, add this logic after rendering this label: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p4mL23yr/

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      render: function() {
        let chart = this,
          credits = chart.options.credits;
        // keep label responsive
        if (chart.customLabel) chart.customLabel.destroy();

        chart.customLabel = chart.renderer
          .label('my custom text', 0, 0).css(credits.style)
          .add();

        chart.customLabel.translate(chart.plotWidth, chart.chartHeight - chart.customLabel.getBBox().height)

        chart.customLabel.on('mouseover', e => {
          chart.myLabel = this.renderer.label(this.title.textStr, e.x - 75, e.y - 50, 'rectangle')
            .css({
              color: '#FFFFFF'
            })
            .attr({
              fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
              padding: 8,
              r: 4,
            })
            .add()
            .toFront();
        });

        chart.customLabel.on('mouseout', e => {
          if (chart.myLabel) {
            chart.myLabel.destroy();
          }
        })
      }
    },
  },
```